# PayPal REST API - List of Refund Transactions

Tags: rest, paypal

A few months ago I asked the following for a List of Sale Transactions:
[PayPal Restful API - Pull List of Sale Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611336/paypal-restful-api-pull-list-of-sale-transactions)

In that question I got an answer referencing the List of Payment Resources call, which is great, but now I need to do something similar for refunds. However it's unclear to me from the documentation whether this includes Refunds.

Does the List of Payment Resources include Refund transactions (which would be a reverse payment of sorts), or is there some other way of accessing a list of Refund transactions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently cannot specifically get a list of refunded transactions. However, as you mention, you can get a list of payments and within that you will see the `state` of the `sale` object as `refunded` and a `refund` object with the `state` of `completed`:

Example:

```
{
            "id": "PAY-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO1234567890",
            "create_time": "2013-09-20T15:44:04Z",
            "update_time": "2013-09-20T16:10:05Z",
            "state": "approved",
            "intent": "sale",
            "payer": {
                "payment_method": "paypal",
                "payer_info": {
                    "email": "bob-facilitator@example.com",
                    "first_name": "Bob",
                    "last_name": "Example",
                    "payer_id": "ABCDEFG123456"
                }
            },
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "amount": {
                        "total": "1.00",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "details": {
                            "subtotal": "1.00"
                        }
                    },
                    "description": "example description",
                    "related_resources": [
                        {
                            "sale": {
                                "id": "ABCDEFGH123456789",
                                "create_time": "2013-09-20T15:44:04Z",
                                "update_time": "2013-09-20T16:10:05Z",
                                "state": "refunded",
                                "amount": {
                                    "total": "1.00",
                                    "currency": "USD"
                                },
                                "parent_payment": "PAY-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO1234567890",
                                "links": [
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/12345678ABCDEFGIJ",
                                        "rel": "self",
                                        "method": "GET"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/12345678ABCDEFGIJ/refund",
                                        "rel": "refund",
                                        "method": "POST"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO1234567890",
                                        "rel": "parent_payment",
                                        "method": "GET"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "refund": {
                                "id": "ABCDEFGH123456789",
                                "create_time": "2013-09-20T16:10:05Z",
                                "update_time": "2013-09-20T16:10:05Z",
                                "state": "completed",
                                "amount": {
                                    "total": "1.00",
                                    "currency": "USD"
                                },
                                "sale_id": "12345678ABCDEFGIJ",
                                "parent_payment": "PAY-57E15446PJ712294VKI6G2RA",
                                "links": [
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/refund/ABCDEFGH123456789",
                                        "rel": "self",
                                        "method": "GET"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO1234567890",
                                        "rel": "parent_payment",
                                        "method": "GET"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/12345678ABCDEFGIJ",
                                        "rel": "sale",
                                        "method": "GET"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO1234567890",
                    "rel": "self",
                    "method": "GET"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Hi Jatin,

Thanks for the response, this is exactly what I was hoping for but could not find in the docs or through samples. 

As a follow-up question: I take it when a Refund transaction is added, the update_time flag on the Payment should be updated, correct?

Comment: Glad to be of help. We'll be sure to include this info in the docs. The update_time should include the last time the payment was acted upon, including refunds. You will see that there is one that is specific to the refund, which matches the parent payment update_time.